# Issues with star environments inside paracol package

Tags: floats, paracol

> This question led to a new vesion 1.32 of `paracol` package.

Basically I want to use the paracol package to set bilingual texts including figures & tables, some of them should span  two columns.

Figures & tables spanning one column work perfect, but with figure* and table* environments spanning two columns, the right column get corrupted. The space needed isn't considered in the right column, resulting in overlapping text with figures*|tables*

MWE, which is based on "[tcolorbox Spanning Two Columns in {paracol} Environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167708/tcolorbox-spanning-two-columns-in-paracol-environment)" and paracol-man:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twoside,a4]{article}

\usepackage[latin,english]{babel} % proper  multilingual hyphenation
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx} % include images
\usepackage{paracol} % multilingual documents

\begin{document}\sloppypar

\begin{paracol}{2}

\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2]
\begin{figure*}
 \def\arraystretch{0.8}
 \centerline{\begin{tabular}[b]{|c|}\hline
 \hbox to.9\textwidth{}\\ \\ \\
 double-column figure \#1\\ \\ \\
 \\\hline
 \end{tabular}}
 \caption{A Double-Column Figure}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[3]
\lipsum[4]

\switchcolumn

\lipsum[5]
\lipsum[6]
\lipsum[7]
\lipsum[8]

\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in (top of pg 2):

[image: top of page 2]

BTW: same effect, if I'm running the MWE of "[tcolorbox Spanning ...](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167708/tcolorbox-spanning-two-columns-in-paracol-environment)"

[image]

**Summary:** I try to understand my issue by using examples I found here, on my computer, always resulting in the same difference: in the right column, the space which should be used for star environments isn't allocated. (using LateX since 1997).

I'm using a fresh install of MiKTeX 2.9

Thanks for any answer,
Marcus

Comment: This is the expected behaviour. If you want something different, then you have to work around it. Here you can break the `paracol` environment to set the two-column figure, or you can line up the two columns and leave the gap manually. Either would work, but it's not clear from your example how you intend to provide bilingual content if they don't match up.

Comment: Hi Werner, the figure and the text are overlapping, which shouldn't happen. If you compare my result (of "tcolorbox Spanning") = overlapping text with the result of [link]http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167708/tcolorbox-spanning-two-columns-in-paracol-environment 2nd page = **no** overlapping!

Comment: @Werner I think this is a bug. It works fine with TeX Live 2014 but not 2015. Should it be reported to the package maintainer, do you think? Or am I missing something? (I don't know this package at all - I just compared the 2014 and 2015 output for a test case.)

Comment: @OP What do you mean that this happens with any LaTeX from 1997 or later?

Comment: @cfr It works fine using this online compiler http://latex.informatik.uni-halle.de/latex-online/latex.php?spw=2&finit=nothing and using `ShareLatex`

Comment: I can confirm the current problem and also that it does not exist in March 2014 with MiKTeX. `paracol` is versioned as `1.31 2013-10-10`. If this is correct, something `paracol` relied on was changed.

Comment: @all: thx++ for your efforts!

Comment: @cfr: I also have the feeling, there is a very nasty side effect/bug. Same effects occur also with a fresh install of TexLive 2015; ad 1997: meaning I'm using Latex since 1997 (not a real newbie anymore).

Comment: @touhami: you are right, using latex-online, which is "TeX Live 2012/Debian" based, produces correct results.

Comment: internal latex commands `\end@dblfloat` and `\@dblfloatplacement` are changed since `v1.2b  2015/01/11` make paracol no more compatible with new format (in this point).

Comment: @touhami: That's worth to be the answer, in my point of view!

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: what touhami just found (thx++ for that!) is the reason for my issue , but not the answer for my problem, how to get it working.

Comment: @MarcusZelezny True, but fixing a bug is really off-topic. You need to tell the package maintainer.

Comment: @all: thanks a lot for your support in identifying the real problem! I already contacted the package owner H. Nakashima. He provided my with a fix and he will provide a new version of `paracol` to CTAN soon.

Comment: @touhami Please read the answer. The package author would like to acknowledge you and is hoping you'll get in touch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm Hiroshi Nakashima, the author of paracol.  I got a message from Marcus today to know an embarrassing change in double-float processing had been made in the latest LaTeX implementation after its stable work for about 30 years to make my paracol unable to work with it.  Fortunately, I could make a quick fix of the problem to have paracol v1.32 to be released soon (hopefully).  I'd like to thank personally to touhami for his/her help by pointing out the change in double-float processing and its impact to paracol.  I hope touhami will contact me so that I express my thanks in "Acknowledgments" of the paracol manual with his/her name.

Comment: Welcome! I've pinged touhami above to draw attention to your request here. (I think you probably don't have enough reputation to do this yet yourself, but I'll vote this up to get you a bit closer!)

Comment: Done, good continuation :-)

Comment: @Hiroshi Nakashima Dear Hiroshi, really thanks a lot for your efforts, to provide us a fix, caused by the change of double-float processing inside the core! Your fix works perfectly!!!

Comment: @touhami thanks also to you, to find the reason for my issue!

Comment: Hiroshi just released his new version 1.32 on CTAN - thx++